Why is my wall primer pulling off as I apply a skim coat?
I've been skimming over painted walls in our bathroom. I sanded, wash this area with tsp, and primed with BIN. After my second coat dried, some areas have bubbled and cause the all purpose drywall mud to pull off the primer even, exposing the original paint. What should I do? Is it alright to sand down the area and patch again? Os there anything else I can do to prevent this from happening elsewhere?

Did you wipe off the dust after sanding?   The compound is sensitive to dust. It sounds like all your primer is peeled off too. too much dust on the walls will allow that.  Also out of curiosity why skimming over the walls?

@RMDman  you make a good point. If the wet mud loosens the paint on the wall, since that paint layer was not prepped for properly it will fail. The OP needs to cut out a bubble with a razor knife and see if the paint has separated with the dried mud.

Please add pics

The post clearly states that the wall was washed after sanding.

@isherwood yes, but if the wash was done in a perfunctory manner, not constantly rinsing and changing water, all it did was push dust around.

If you used TSP did you thoroughly rinse after? TSP is heavy duty and no matter what requires multiples rinses with plain water.
Also, try a bonding primer instead of BIN, and if you're doing a skim coat and getting a bubble that also sounds like its too thick.
Remember skim coating often takes several thin coats; it's never a one and done.
